# Unable to connect to Postgres service using docker and tox

Tags: python, django, docker, tox

I have a docker application that builds a Postgres database. I am using tox to run my Django tests. When I am running `docker-compose run web tox` over my docker image in my local machine (I used `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate -d` to build my docker image) it is showing error as:

> ```
> E       django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server:                     
>         Connection refused
> E       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
> E       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

But when I am running the only tox command  (not on my docker image) it is working fine.

I tried to run my Django test without tox that is by using `docker-compose run web python manage.py test` over my docker image. In this case, it is not showing any errors. I guess I have some problem to run tox over my docker image.

Comment: Add your compose file and python DB connection config.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue while the DB was definitely running. Turns out Tox doesn't pass the env variables from the host machine into the test environment unless you tell it to, so Django was trying to connect with the wrong DB settings.

The fix was to use the [`passenv`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-passenv) option in the Tox.ini file to pass the required variables:

```
[testenv]
deps = -r requirements.txt
commands = pytest {posargs}
passenv = POSTGRES_USER POSTGRES_PASSWORD POSTGRES_HOST POSTGRES_PORT
```

You could also use `passenv = *` to pass everything.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by well known thing, that the test container starts before DB container is fully functional. Although you set in docker compose dependency/link docker only waits for the dependent container to be up. If DB initialization takes say 30s, the second container will be started before that and you will see this issue.

Solution is to put in place on the second container some bash script that will ping the DB port to make it wait with until the DB is ready. Check SO, there are multiple similar questions with some nice solutions how to make second container wait for the dependent DB.